# OnActivityResult Android is not triggered

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, xamarin.android, onactivityresult

I've a problem with Xamarin.Android, when I scanned a QRCode who contain some products infos and launch an activity (`StartActivityForResult`) for borrow and finish the other activity, it doesn't trigger `OnActivityResult`.

When I start the activity:

```
    scannerButton.Click += async delegate
{
    MobileBarcodeScanner.Initialize(Application);

    var scanner = new MobileBarcodeScanner();

    var qrValue = await scanner.Scan();

    if (qrValue != null)
    {
        string[] infosProduct = qrValue.Text.Split(',');

        ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progress.SetMessage("En cour...");
        progress.SetTitle("Vérification du statut de l'objet");
        progress.SetProgressStyle(ProgressDialogStyle.Spinner);
        progress.SetCancelable(false);
        progress.Show();

        bool? borrowed = DbManager.getInstance().isProductBorrowed(Convert.ToInt32(infosProduct[0]));

        progress.Dismiss();

        if (borrowed == true) 
        {                     
            Toast.MakeText(this, "todo : rendre produit", ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }
        else if (borrowed == false)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(BorrowActivity));
            intent.PutExtra("user", settings.GetString("user", ""));
            intent.PutExtra("infosProduct", infosProduct);
            StartActivityForResult(intent,0);
        }
    }
};
```

The onResult

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
        {
            // TODO Refresh
            Toast.MakeText(this, "test", ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }
    }
```

When I send result:

```
borrowButton.Click += delegate {

Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MenuActivity));
                        SetResult(Result.Ok, intent);
                        Finish();
                    }
```

Comment: What is your `Activity` launchMode ? Please post your `Activity` attribute ?

Comment: Sorry for late answer, here my attribute (I don't have launchMode)
[Activity(Label = "MenuActivity")]
[MetaData("com.google.android.gms.vision.DEPENDENCIES", Value = "barcode")]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, the problem was that my Activiy where I have "OnActivityResult" hasn't the param "MainLauncher = true" or it just solves with recreate the project. I used @Justinas answer too but it works only when I recreate project and use the param. So I don't really know for which reason it works, but it works c:

Answer (score 0):

Try to change in activity:

> Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(BorrowActivity));

to

> Intent intent = new Intent(this,
>   typeof(BorrowActivity)).SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ReorderToFront);

If it wont't help i don't have any idea. I have similar problem.
In my case it's possible that latest update of xamarin or visual studio cause problem, because in one of three computers same code works perfectly and that compuster is still not updated.

Comment: Sorry for late answer, unfortunately it doesn't work.